# Back button works randomly

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

My phonegap app basically has two "pages", which are actually just a div having it's content changed by innerHTML. The back key is meant to quit the app when pressed on the "home page" (div id=`num`) and return to the homepage when pressed on the second page (div id=`readout`), to copy normal android habits. I defined a boolean `home` to keep a track on which page it's on and to make the `onBackKeyDown()` do different things:

```
function onBackKeyDown() {
            if(home==true){
                navigator.notification.alert(
            'Bye!',  // message
            'Quitting',            // title
            'oops')
                navigator.app.exitApp();
            }
            else {
                resetAll();}
        }
```

However the back key's behaviour on the `readout` page is changing depending on if a particular function `dispatch()` has been run or not yet. If it hasn't been run yet the back key will quit the app straight away (without triggering `onBackKeyDown()` since I added an extra alert when that function quits the app)

`dispatch()` doesn't seem to have anything to do with `home` or the back key, so I haven't got a clue what the problem is. `home` seems to be correct all the time when I try it in firebug. Here's `dispatch`:

```
function dispatch()
        {
            navigator.notification.vibrate(50);

            d= new Date();
            times[i]=d.getTime();


            if(i==0)
            {
                 document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = 'Calculating...';
                 document.getElementById('avDisTime').innerHTML ='Calculating...';
            }


            else
            {
                var avTime=getAverageTime(times);

                var throughput=passengers*3600000/avTime;

                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = throughput.toFixed(0) + ' pph';

                document.getElementById('avDisTime').innerHTML =(avTime/1000).toFixed(0)+' seconds';
            }

            return false;
        }
```

and [here is the whole page](http://pastebin.com/1mUAsQDU). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem could be you´re overwriting the default backbutton behaviour when firing the onBackKeyDown() function. regardless of the problem with the dispatch() function, try to add this line inside your onBackKeyDown() Function.

```
document.removeEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);
```

it restores the default backbutton behavior of the app.

Comment: I intended to overwrite it, so it would reset the app when pressed on the readout page. The default behaviour is to quit whereever you are